# Hosting internal Nuget and Symbols server

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I have setup the Nuget.Server and the SymbolSource Server Basic in one solution when I run the "self diagnostics tool" I get the following exception, anyone have a clue what this is?

The URL I am accessing is

```
http://localhost/Home/NuGetPushTest
```

> Method not found: 'Void NuGet.PackageServer.PushPackage(System.String,
>   System.IO.Stream, Int32)'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Void NuGet.PackageServer.PushPackage(System.String, System.IO.Stream,
>   Int32)'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look at [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) - it's a lot easier to set-up, and the feed edition supports nuget/symbol serving (disclaimer: I work for Inedo)